# Is there a way to apply .ConfigureAwait(false) to a whole task subtree?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have a class that runs thousands of async tasks in parallel which is much greater than amount of worker threads. If I don't do `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on await calls then I get much lower performance but attaching `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to every single await call is tedious and reduces code readability. I'm looking for a way to specify some kind of null context in a function that spawns those tasks so that every await call inside them automatically doesn't care about SynchronizationContext. Is it possible?

*Update:* I've done some googling and it looks like once I'm already inside a function with `.ConfigureAwait(false)` the current SynchronizationContext will be null and I don't need to care about it in child function calls. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, and I think that using `true` as the default in `ConfigureAwait` was a big mistake, too.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, not agree about default value "mistake". When you call method asynchronously you "by default" expect that continuation will be executed in same "context".

Comment: @Fabio As far as I know, the only place where it really matters is UI. In other places you do not care about it, at least, you do not care strongly enough to agree to reduced performance and a possibility of deadlocks.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, usually call hierarchy of async methods will end in the UI, where all results will be "awaited" and exceptions are handled. So executing result in same context by default seems logical solution. Of course this solution can be argued in same way as "big" and "small endians". For example for `ASP.NET` application context usually not important.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. By resetting the current SynchronizationContext.

At the top level async method do this:

```
async Task TopLevelAsync()
{
    var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
    try
    {
        // no need for ConfigureAwait(false)
        await SubTask1Async();
        await SubTask2Async();
    }
    finally
    {
         SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncContext);
    }
}
```

> once I'm already inside a function with .ConfigureAwait(false) the current SynchronizationContext will be null and I don't need to care about it in child function calls. Is that correct?

Unfortunately, it's not. It's a dangerous assumption. And here is why:

```
// in a top-level async method..
await FooAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

async Task FooAsync()
{
    var result = await BarAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    // we are inside the ConfigureAwait(false), or in the
    // continuation after ConfigureAwait(false), so at this
    // point the SynchronizationContext must be null, right?
    // No it's not.
}

Task<bool> BarAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

From the example above the `BarAsync` completes synchronously, that means the state machine behind the `FooAsync` method continues it's execution immediately without re-scheduling. Without re-scheduling logic, the `ConfigureAwait(false)` does not taken into an account, so the SynchronizationContext is never reset.

Comment: Design as in case of `BarAsync` is either for calling some synchronous events or mock testing, possible case but not a very standard scenario, since OP is assuming complete Async call chain

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, not necessarily. There are a lot of examples of such real code. Image when you have multiple data providers, where consumer can aggregate them. One of those providers can be an in-memory implementation. However, all of them implement the same interface which is async to make sure are not blocking a thread if a provider does some sort of IO. And once again, even a real async IO task can complete before you check the state of the result `Task` variable.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, the very basic example is `SemaphoreSlim`, which uses spin lock first and can complete synchronously, what provides the best performance instead of always using the `WaitHandle`. One of the C# 7 features is to allow custom types instead of using `Task` or `Task<7>`, which is designed specifically for synchronous completion in an async method.

Answer (score 2):

> it looks like once I'm already inside a function with .ConfigureAwait(false) the current SynchronizationContext will be null and I don't need to care about it in child function calls. Is that correct?

Well, the *actual* situation is:

- You're inside an asynchronous function.
- You start a task.
- You do an `await` (configured with `false`) on that task before it completes.

So, it's not a great situation to depend on. Specifically, if the task completes quickly (before your configured `await` is hit), then you will still be on the original context. Note that this can happen even if you don't expect it to; for example, mobile devices are extremely aggressive about caching web requests.

To "step out" of the synchronization context, just wrap it in a `Task.Run` - this uses a thread pool thread very briefly, and executes all the descendant code in that thread pool context.

Comment: So I never need to use a ConfigureAwait when I'm inside a Task.Run?

Comment: @Poma: `ConfigureAwait` has no effect when called within a `Task.Run`. If your code **knows** it will **always** be called from within a `Task.Run`, then yes, you can skip it.

Comment: `You do an await (configured with false) on that task before it completes.` - this is incorrect assumption. There is no guarantee that Task completes after you call a method that returns a Task. The Task can be returned already in a complete state.

Comment: @SergeSemenov: That's exactly the point of my answer. Try reading it again.

Comment: Won't it be preferable that you don't use `ConfigureAwait` anywhere and execute the `Async` methods and use the `Task.WhenAll`to map the synchronization context

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: I'm not sure what you're suggesting. `WhenAll` is normally only used with asynchronous fork/join concurrency, and doesn't have anything to do with `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: @StephenCleary, ah, ok, i see. Just the first part of the answer is confusing with an emphasis on an 'actual' situation

Comment: @Stephen Cleary, I was certainly mixed up, especially because I always make my whole call chain `Async` and use `Task.WhenAll` to coordinate, nullifying the `Synchronization Context` is never part of plan